# When is $x^3 - 2$ congruent to $ 0 \pmod p$ not solvable?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I want to find for what primes $p$ is the congruence $x^3 \equiv 2$ (mod $p$) is not solvable. I already know that $p = 7$ is one result from my own work but I'm trying to generalize this to find for what primes $p$ modulo an integer where the congruence is not solvable. I'm not sure, but I think that I can use cubic reciprocity but I've hit a wall and I haven't been able to move on from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [cubic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity).

Answer (score 1):

The primes are those with an integer expression
$$ p = 4 u^2 + 2uv+ 7 v^2,  $$
where $uv$ is allowed positive or negative or zero, as might be required.
Theorem of Gauss. As a reference, this is Proposition 9.6.2 in Ireland and Rosen. The way they put it: if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ then $2$ has a cube root if there are integers $C,D$ such that $p = C^2 + 27 D^2.$ They do not sem to mention the alternative: if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and we cannot write $p = C^2 + 27 D^2,$ then there are integers (not necessarily positive ) $u,v$ such that $p = 4 u^2 + 2 uv + 7 v^2.$ In Cox, ***Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2,$*** this is Theorem 4.15 in my edition, and (4,2,7) is displayed back on page 29, table (2.14). The fundamental (and entirely constructive) theorem is that any prime for which a discriminant is a quadratic residue ( and the prime does not divide the discriminant) is integrally represented by a (primitive) form of that discriminant.

Here are such primes up to 1000

```
  7,     13,     19,     37,     61,     67,     73,     79,     97,    103,
139,    151,    163,    181,    193,    199,    211,    241,    271,    313,
331,    337,    349,    367,    373,    379,    409,    421,    463,    487,
523,    541,    547,    571,    577,    607,    613,    619,    631,    661,
673,    709,    751,    757,    769,    787,    823,    829,    853,    859,
877,    883,    907,    937,    967,    991,
```

Well, why not. The primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ for which $x^3 - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ does have a solution, indeed three solutions, are those with $p = C^2 + 27 D^2.$ Here they are up to 1000:

```
  1,     31,     43,    109,    127,    157,    223,    229,    277,    283,
307,    397,    433,    439,    457,    499,    601,    643,    691,    727,
733,    739,    811,    919,    997,
```

Oh, my program lists $1$ as a prime, not traditional. Too much effort to change it at this point.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. What Gauss theorem are you referring to?

Comment: @willjagy An explanation of how you got that expression for $p$, and what $u$ and $v$ are would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is soluble if $p\equiv0$ or $2\pmod3$. If $p\equiv1\pmod3$
then we can write $p=|a+b\omega|^2$ where $a$, $b\in \Bbb Z$ and
$\omega=\frac12(-1+i\sqrt3)$, that is $p=a^2-ab+b^2$.
In addition, we can assume that $\pi$ is primary, that is $3\mid b$.
Write $\pi=a+b\omega$.

By cubic reciprocity, $x^3\equiv2\pmod p$ is soluble if
$\left(\frac2{\pi}\right)_3=1$. (This is a cubic Legendre symbol).
But $\left(\frac2{\pi}\right)_3=\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)_3$
(cubic reciprocity). Now $\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)_3=1$ iff $b$
is even. So $x^3\equiv2\pmod p$ is insoluble if $p\equiv1\pmod 3$
and $p=a^2-ab+b^2$ with $b$ an odd multiple of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

In order for $x^3-2=0\pmod p$ not to be solvable (no integer solutions $x$), $p=1\pmod 3$ and $2$ is a cubic non-residue $\pmod p$.

The harder question to ask is, when is $2$ a cubic non-residue?

Many articles, and research on cubic reciprocity are known, and $2$ is a cubic residue $\pmod p$ if and only if $p=x^2+27y^2$. If $p=1\pmod 3$ is not of this form, then $x^3-2=0\pmod p$ is not solvable.